# Converting project to Visual Studio 2012 WinRT, can't setup directx libraries

Tags: directx, visual-studio-2012

I'm converting a DirectX project to a WinRT project in Visual Studio 2012 and having trouble setting up references to the Direct X libraries. I'm using at a generated Direct3D solution as a guide. I've added what I think are the correct include folders and libs in the project settings but I must be missing something else. In the generated Direct3D solution, the "External Dependencies" tree in the Solution Explorer has a whole bunch of directx headers in there, but I have no idea how that is set up. Simply dragging and dropping DirectX headers doesn't work, which didn't really surprise me.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the problem again with a fresh head, I noticed that the generated DirectX example was using a precompiled header while the project I'm working with wasn't. The precompiled header was including DirectX headers that my project wasn't.

So I added

```
#include <DirectXmath.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
```

and it compiled.